# How to transfer blame from a deleted file to it's replacement?

Tags: mercurial

I started with the file `OldController.php` and converted it to `NewController.php`. Here's my workflow:

- Commit: Delete `OldController.php` and create `NewController.php`
- Amend: Do some work on `NewController.php`
- Amend: Do more work on `NewController.php`

(Pretty sure the amends hold no relevance, but figured I'd mention them anyways.)

So, how do I take the history of `OldController.php` and point it to `NewController.php`?

I know I can just go back and do this manually, but I'd like to know how to do this within mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

Update back to the last revision where `OldController.php` still existed. At that point, use `hg mv` to effectively rename it to `NewController.php`. Commit that rename. This creates a new head.

At that point you have a few options:

1. Merge the commit you just made with the other head which already had `NewController.php`
2. Rebase everything starting with the first commit to include `NewController.php` onto the new head you just created.

Either way would be effective, but it depends on whether you want to preserve the history of this change, or you're OK just to make it look like you had renamed it from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hg cp` (or `hg mv` if you only want to rename the file) instead of deleting one file and newly creating the other. That way mercurial knows that the new file is based on the old one and will display history accordingly